# Can I connect to mysql using Psycopg2 lib

Tags: python, mysql, orm, database-connection

I have a project in python that connects to a postgreSQL database.

That project have a module that connects to other data base. The connection string is on a configuration file. I configure it to use a mysql database like this:

```
database_url = mysql://user:password@localhost/database
```

One running the module I always get the following error:

> line 179, in connect
> connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async) psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for
> user "tmp" FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "user"

I know that all the communication to the data base is made by the python ORM SQLAlchemy and that this ORM supports MySQL DBs.

I don't known why I get a authentication error sent by the psycopg2 lib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLAlchemy supports different dialects to connect to various databases with appropriate driver. Both MySQL and PostgreSQL are supported. You would use psycopg2 to connect to Postgres and e.g. MySQLdb to connect to MySQL. You also have to change the connection string.

See here for details: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html

Comment: My problem is that I was using  psycopg2 to connect to MySQL databases.